# @WebServlet annotation and error 404

Tags: servlets, java-ee-6

First of all: I use GlassFish 3.1 + Eclipse Java EE indigo.
I want to testing cache solutions with javaee so I made a dummy app. I have a big generated database and I list, search, modify, etc some data. To do that I wrote some basic servlet and I call with GET parameters. e.g.: /app/list?page=product&pageSize=100
The ListServlet is annotated with

```
@WebServlet({ "/ListServlet", "/list" })
```

and it works like a charm, I can use both urls.
So I need some additional servlet (for search, modify). I created them and annotated the same way. 
But when I type the url `http://localhost/app/modify` or /app/search?id=1 I get error 404. 
I tried to write a very dummy helloservlet which is print a hello world message but it didn't work: error 404. I restarted the glassfish server and the computer but not helped.

What's the problem? Did I miss something?

EDIT:
the servlets are the same package uses the same imports...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure your url patterns are correct? Try something like this:

```
@WebServlet( name="ListServlet", displayName="ListServlet", urlPatterns = {"/list","/modify", "/search"}, loadOnStartup=1)
```

If you want all the patterns go into the same servlet. If not, you would have to have a different servlets for each pattern, and those servlets should be named differently I guess.

Anyway, for this kind of behaviour I would recommend using for example [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) routing.

**EDITED:**

I tested it. Here you have my servlets working like a charm:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(asyncSupported = false, name = "HelloServlet1", urlPatterns = {"/hello1"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("<h2>Hello Servlet One </h2>");
        out.close();
    }


}
```

and the second one:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(asyncSupported = false, name = "HelloServlet2", urlPatterns = {"/hello2"})
public class TestServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("<h2>Hello Servlet Two </h2>");
        out.close();
    }


}
```

I do call them like: http://localhost:8080/eetest/hello1 and http://localhost:8080/eetest/hello2 and they print 'Hello Servlet One' and 'Hello Servlet Two' respectivelly.
(tested on JBoss AS 7 - web profile)

Comment: Sorry maybe I haven't written clearly enough: I have seperate servlets. ListServlet, ModifyServlet, SearchServlet in same package but with different @WebServlet annotation.

Comment: Interesting :). Then maybe try to change your patterns to smth like "/list/*", "/modify/*" etc

Comment: I tried a lot of things but something wrong... "/list/*" doesn't help. The list servlet is working the other two is not. What a riddle...

Comment: can you post @webservlet annotatios from all your servlets?

Comment: Yepp
    @WebServlet({ "/ListServlet", "/list" })
    @WebServlet({ "/HelloServlet", "/hello" })
    @WebServlet(name="modify", urlPatterns={ "/modify" }, loadOnStartup=1)
Only ListServlet works.

Comment: Hmmm I found a very interesting thing: if I delete the listservlet (which is working) and try to access in the url it still working... I restarted glassfish, and redeployed the app... I don't understand, but it seems like a stucked project in the app server. So I can do anything in my code: nothing changed in the browser. I'll try to reinstall glassfish.

Comment: Ok, reinstall and redeploy - it's work.
Thank you for your help! Your example is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the problem was a forgotten import statement in my servlet. Make sure your servlet is compiling correctly.